Changing color in Inkscape and importing in Xcode keeps the color black when using a SVG file
I have this SVG:

I made the 'blood' red, the original was black. These are the color settings:

Importing the SVG file in Xcode keeps the blood black, the original color of the SVG: 
I don't know what I am missing. I edited the color on a different site, imported the SVG again and then Xcode was showing the blood in red, so it's something Inkscape related. This is the original SVG: https://jumpshare.com/s/MnEHzYteNeOgaNBX11y7 (download .svg file can be done right above -> download)

Hi. Was this SVG actually created in Inkscape? I notice it has some unnecessary nesting: there's a group within a layer within a layer. Some software can have issues with excessive nesting.  Try Selecting all, and then do ungroup 3 times.  That should remove them.  I don't know if this will work with your other software. It's just a guess. Give it a go.  Also when you have done that, save it as a "Plain SVG" to remove the Inkscape-specific XML which can sometimes cause issues in other software.
